# How do I validly make it so a webpage can scroll y but not x?

Tags: html, css, validation

I'm trying to make a web-page with a 100% with div with padding, but when I do this I end up with a horizontal scroll bar. So I'm adding overflow: hidden to the bod to fix it, but it prevents me from scrolling on the y-axis. So How can I get just the x axis to be overflow: hidden?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to mess with the scrollbars. Just create another `div` in the current one for `padding`.

**[[Demo](http://jsbin.com/emoga4/2)]**

```
<style>
#outer { width:100%; } 
#inner { padding:50px; }
</style>

<div id="outer">
    <div id="inner">100% width with padding</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

try overflow-x:hidden; This should work

Comment: That works, but it's not vaild css according to the validator:(

Comment: It's a CSS3 property. What you should really do is restructure the HTML/CSS as galambalazs was saying.